# Lower bound on a spanning set projecting onto any one dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, projection

Suppose $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a spanning set. Let $V$ be an arbitrary one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. I am wondering whether there is a constant $c = c(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ independent of $V$, such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \langle P_V x_i, P_V x_i \rangle \ge c$ where $P_V$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $V$.

Comment: Is $P_V$ the orthogonal projection onto $V$? Given a subspace, there are many projections you could choose.

Comment: It’s orthogonal projection. Thanks.